# Split string with three words

Tags: java, string, loops, split

### What is the best way to split a string containing three words?

My code looks like this right now (see below for updated code):

```
BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));

        String line;
        int i = 0;

        while ((line = infile.readLine()) != null) {
            String first, second, last;
            //Split line into first, second and last (word)

            //Do something with words (no help needed)
            i++;
        }
```

Here is the full file.txt:

> ```
> Allegrettho     Albert          0111-27543
> Brio            Britta          0113-45771
> Cresendo        Crister         0111-27440
> Dacapo          Dan             0111-90519
> Dolce           Dolly           0116-31418
> Espressivo      Eskil           0116-19042
> Fortissimo      Folke           0118-37547
> Galanto         Gunnel          0112-61805
> Glissando       Gloria          0112-43918
> Grazioso        Grace           0112-43509
> Hysterico       Hilding         0119-71296
> Interludio      Inga            0116-22709
> Jubilato        Johan           0111-47678
> Kverulando      Kajsa           0119-34995
> Legato          Lasse           0116-26995
> Majestoso       Maja            0116-80308
> Marcato         Maria           0113-25788
> Molto           Maja            0117-91490
> Nontroppo       Maistro         0119-12663
> Obligato        Osvald          0112-75541
> Parlando        Palle           0112-84460
> Piano           Pia             0111-10729
> Portato         Putte           0112-61412
> Presto          Pelle           0113-54895
> Ritardando      Rita            0117-20295
> Staccato        Stina           0112-12107
> Subito          Sune            0111-37574
> Tempo           Kalle           0114-95968
> Unisono         Uno             0113-16714
> Virtuoso        Vilhelm         0114-10931
> Xelerando       Axel            0113-89124
> ```

New code as @Pshemo suggested:

```
public String load() {
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("reg.txt"));

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String firstname = scanner.next();
            String lastname = scanner.next();
            String number = scanner.next();
            list.add(new Entry(firstname, lastname, number));
        }
        msg = "The file reg.txt has been opened";
        return msg;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
            msg = ("Can't find reg.txt");
            return msg;
    } catch (IOException ie) {
            msg = ("Can't find reg.txt");
            return msg;
    }
}
```

I receive multiple errors, what's wrong?

Comment: You need to use `String#split`, but need to know where to split the string.

Comment: Give sample input and output.. What is the criteria for splitting?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add. Coming...

Comment: @WhoAmI "criteria for splitting" ... them's the words I was looking for.

Comment: You need to split with `"\\s+"`.

Comment: What are your errors? I don't see any declaration of `msg` and `list` in your method. I assume that `list` is field but `msg` should probably be local variable of `load` method.

Comment: @Pshemo `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
        at lab6.Read.load(Read.java:21)`

`msg`is declared before.

Comment: Is it possible that lines can contain different number of words then three? I mean case like empty lines (like last line) or lines with persons info like `Bruce Lee Third 0111-90519`?

Comment: @Pshemo Unfortunately not, I've posted the full file above.

Comment: Your code (with added `msg` and `list`) works fine for me on file you provided. Probably problem lies somewhere else. I would suggest creating new question with full but simplified code [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and data which could be used to reproduce your problem. Also make sure that there really is no empty line in your data file (like at the end of it).

Comment: @Pshemo There is an empty line at the end of the file, is there anyway to ignore it? I will remove it, but just out of curiosity.

Comment: You could change `scanner.hasNextLine()` to `scanner.hasNext()`. Your code would be less readable but this way you would only use `scanner.next()` if there would really be next (non whitespace) element to read. Also this would work only for first element (`firstname `), so if line would not contain three elements you will see same error for `lastname` or `number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each line always contains exactly three words instead of split you can simply use `Scanner`s method `next` three times for each line.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
int i = 0;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String first = scanner.next();
    String second = scanner.next();
    String last = scanner.next();
    //System.out.println(first+": "+second+": "+last);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Could you take a look at the code above and see what's wrong? It guess it's the catch-statements that are wrong somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
line.split("\\s+"); // don't use " ". use "\\s+" for more than one whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the line has 3+ words, use the `split(delimiter)` method:

```
String line = ...;

String[] parts = line.split("\\s+"); // Assuming words are separated by whitespaces, use another if required
```

then you can access to the first, second and last respectively:

```
String first = parts[0];
String second = parts[1];
String last = parts[parts.length() - 1];
```

Remember that indexes starts with 0.

Comment: Assume I'm taking care of each string without creating an array. How would I write it?

Comment: `split` automatically creates an array, no way around that.

Comment: Okay, if I'm not using `split` then? Sorry for changing my mind but I thought it was possible to use `split` without creating an array. Thanks for the help so far though.

Comment: @mouduor - Give sample output. we can tell you whether split() is a good option

Comment: I'm using a class Entry to save the words into list.
`list.add(new Entry(first, second, last));`

Answer (score 0):

```
String []parts=line.split("\\s+");

System.out.println(parts[0]);
System.out.println(parts[1]);
System.out.println(parts[parts.length-1]);
```

Comment: split(" ") splits based on single whitespace. split("\\s+") splits based on 1 or more whitespaces.